# Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in drupal_write_record()

Tags: 7, users

I'm building a new Drupal 7 and brought over the user table at the beginning of the project from another Drupal 7 site. All has been good with that except that when users save their profile, they get the following error, which I believe is related to our custom Avatar builder module. I am wondering what I can do to suspend the error message so that it doesn't show for now during our testing phase.

> Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in
>   drupal_write_record() (line 7340

Here is the section of code from the .module that I believe that relates to this error:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert().
 */
function my_avatar_selection_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (isset($account->picture)) {  
    $usage = new stdClass;
    $usage->uid = $account->uid;
    $usage->fid = $account->picture;
    drupal_write_record('my_avatar_selection_usage', $usage);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_update().
 */
function my_avatar_selection_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {  
  if (isset($account->picture)) {  
    $usage = new stdClass;
    $usage->uid = $account->uid;
    $usage->fid = $account->picture;
    $has_rows = (bool) db_query_range('SELECT 1 FROM {my_avatar_selection_usage} WHERE uid = :uid', 0, 1, array(':uid' => $account->uid))->fetchField();
    if ($has_rows) {
      drupal_write_record('my_avatar_selection_usage', $usage, 'uid');
    }
    else {
      drupal_write_record('my_avatar_selection_usage', $usage);
    }
  }
}
```

The module works by saving the data from jcarousel into the data field of the user table and when the profile is saved, it creates a graphic that looks like the options the users selected. As far as I can tell, there are no issues with saving the avatar, it just generates this error. I took this module from the old website 7.50 so maybe there is a component I don't need on the new site 7.54.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused from the fact `$account->picture` is an object, and `drupal_write_record()` is trying to convert it to an integer, since the *my_avatar_selection_usage* defines *fid* as an integer value. See the following code used from [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7.x), which the function invoking `hook_user_insert()`.

```
  // Process picture uploads.
  if (!empty($account->picture->fid) && (!isset($account->original->picture->fid) || $account->picture->fid != $account->original->picture->fid)) {
    $picture = $account->picture;

    // Omissis

  }
```

As you see from that code, the correct code you should be using is the following one.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert().
 */
function my_avatar_selection_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (isset($account->picture)) {  
    $usage = new stdClass;
    $usage->uid = $account->uid;
    $usage->fid = $account->picture->fid;
    drupal_write_record('my_avatar_selection_usage', $usage);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_update().
 */
function my_avatar_selection_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {  
  if (isset($account->picture)) {  
    $usage = new stdClass;
    $usage->uid = $account->uid;
    $usage->fid = $account->picture->fid;
    $has_rows = (bool) db_query_range('SELECT 1 FROM {my_avatar_selection_usage} WHERE uid = :uid', 0, 1, array(':uid' => $account->uid))->fetchField();
    if ($has_rows) {
      drupal_write_record('my_avatar_selection_usage', $usage, 'uid');
    }
    else {
      drupal_write_record('my_avatar_selection_usage', $usage);
    }
  }
}
```